# session_start() always in profiler

Tags: php, session, shopware

I am using an APP (Shopware) and it seems that on almost every page (when I am not logged in) it trys to start a session - and it takes 1s, 3s, 5s or 9s - which is not normal. Because usually it takes only ms and also it is not always the same value (and exactly seconds).

The stack from tideways shows this:

```
#1 session_start
#2 Zend_Session::start
#3 Shopware\Components\DependencyInjection\Bridge\Session::createSession
#4 ShopwareProduction057457c96467d4f1d33bee870a96ef43d2ed5e07ProjectContainer::getSessionService
#5 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::get
#6 Shopware\Components\DependencyInjection\Container::doLoad
#7 Shopware\Components\DependencyInjection\Container::get
#8 Shopware\Models\Shop\Shop::registerResources
#9 Shopware_Plugins_Core_Router_Bootstrap::onRouteStartup
#10 Enlight_Event_Handler_Plugin::execute

Parent Spans

PARENT Http​Cache::forward()
```

I know its few, but I thought somebody might has an idea what it could be. I am not too familiar with php sessions.

We are using memcached btw

Comment: Try to call session_write_close() when you're done with the session.

Comment: Well I am not even sure what is stating the session